# Selenium WebDriver with Polymer website and Shadow root

Tags: java, html, selenium

In Google Chrome console I can click on Shadow root element by this.

```
document.querySelector('html /deep/ next-tab').querySelector('a').click()
```

But I did same thing with web-driver java code did not work .

Here is my web-driver & java code.

```
WebElement result = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html /deep/ next-tab")).findElement(By.cssSelector("html /deep/ a");

result.click();
```

Can anyone help me with this? It is very simple thing but somehow I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `shadowRoot` property in javascript rather than `deep` is deprecated:

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExecuter = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement result = jsExecuter.executeScript('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)    
result.click();
```

Where `argument[0]` is the `html` in your case.

**Elaboration:** With `WebDriver` you have the option to execute javascript after you cast the driver to executor. With `JavascriptExecutor` you run javascript code directly to the page. Selenium doesn't support `shadowRoot` out of the box, so we need this casting.

In order to just do what you want (clicking an element inside a #shadow-root):

```
jsExecuter.executeScript("return document.querySelector('html').shadowRoot.querySelector('next-tab').querySelector('a').click()");
```

**Edit:** In order to click "Electronics & Applicances" you'll need:

```
jsExecuter.executeScript("document.querySelector('next-app').shadowRoot.querySelector('next-app-header').shadowRoot.querySelector('app-header').querySelector('next-nav-bar').shadowRoot.querySelector('div.bar').querySelector('next-tabs > next-tab').click();");
```

Do you see where this is going? every time you need an element (html tag) under a `shadow-root` you'll need to use `.shadowRoot` and then `querySelector('cssSelector')` to get the element you want.

Then you can click this element, or send keys to it etc... I've put a lot of effort to this question, now it's your turn ;)

Comment: Can you please elaborate more in details? I am not much into java-script. It would be nice if you can write down some code over here using my above example. Thanks

Comment: I am getting this error org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null -----------------------------------------------------JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; ---------------------------------------I can also provide my web-site, if you want to dig into more.     
  
  js.executeScript("return document.querySelector('html').shadowRoot.querySelector('next-tab').querySelector('a').click()");

Comment: Yes please do add a link.

Comment: Here is my link

Comment: https://cp-web.nextcake.net/. I want to click on Search button enter something like cake. One wired thing is when you hit the enter using SendKeys.RETURN or SendKeys.ENTER did not work at all. I also want to click on Electronics & Applicances. It would be appreciated, if you can provide full code.

Comment: web-site start with https

Comment: The website isn't loading, but from what I saw on other Polymer website you don't need the shadow root / deep part. Does the a your looking for has an id or class?

Comment: (https://cp-web-nextcake.net) or (https://cp-web-sit.nextcake.net/) try one of this.  please use https

Comment: (https://shop.polymer-project.org/) If nothing works then please show me the demo on this website to click on Men's Outerwear or shop now button